# Custom map marker in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I am creating a GPS Location Map project that display current users location in map,I want to display the user's phone number on marker click like winInfo, how to do that

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin/

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is in this article: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin/

Comment: thank you, I see recipe but I want the user save his number to database and then populate the number on his marker on map, or when marker click send notification message like taxi app